# mod rewrite - why the trailing slash is not optional here?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I got some rules in my .htaccess I use ?/ to make the trailing slash optional, but in the last of my rueles it doesn't work. The page loads only if the slash is present, otherwise the server gives a 404 error

The last two rules are:

```
RewriteRule ^page?/$ page.php
RewriteRule ^otherpage/([a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+)?/$ otherpage.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

I can't understand why, what should I do to make the trailing slash in the last rule optional?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: `?` makes the preceding character/group optional, not the following one.

Comment: @mario ?I thought it was this way around

Comment: As mario says, you are making the `e` optional, not the `/`

Comment: Thank you! It's so obvious now that you pointed it out! Where was my head?
Now all works smooth!
Cheers!